# Run multiple Python scripts in Blender from the command-line

Tags: python, scripting, command-line

I have 8 python scripts and I need to lunch them at once. For one script, I used

```
blender --background --python script1.py
```

for the eight scripts, I tried this command but it does not work.

```
blender --background --python *.py
```

Answer (score 5):

You can have multiple `--python` tags. For example:

```
blender --background --python script1.py --python script2.py
```

This will execute the scripts in the order they are added in the command above. Add as many `--python` arguments as you need (there is no limit on the number of scripts you can run).

Comment: I have already tried this but it did not work

Comment: Then I think you may need to add more information to your question as this method worked just now when I tried it. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I think the problem is that they run in sequence and not in parallel, but they do all 'run at once' depending on your meaning of the term. They do not run 'simultaneously'