# How to write a python script that opens My_file.blend and applies a script on it?

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

My main goal is to achieve that this script file will open My_file.blend, apply my script on it, render and save an image to output path

Comment: Do you intend that the script also starts Blender or would it already be open?

Comment: I intend that the script also starts Blender, doing the script, and then save an image

Comment: that will require two separate scripts. One for starting Blender and one for performing actions in Blender.

Comment: See https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html for more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the Blender command line interface (CLI) to trigger the script execution and rendering. The CLI is described in the [Blender documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/command_line/arguments.html?highlight=command%20line).

For instance you could start Blender from the command line, let it run a python script and then render a frame using the following command (you will have to add the correct paths to the relevant files). The following command renders frame 0 of project.blend after the script.py has been executed.

`.\blender.exe project.blend -b -P script.py -o //frame_ -f 0`

`-b` or `--background` starts Blender without a user interface.

`-P` or `--python` allows to run a script.

`-o` or `--render-output` defines how the rendered files will be named and where they will be stored. `//` denotes the current working directory.

`-f` or `--render-frame` tells Blender to render a specific frame.

In case you don't want to execute Blender with this command manually, you can use `subprocess` in a another python script to start Blender. The following function is an example of how you could start Blender from another python script. As arguments you need to pass the path to Blender, the project and the script and it will start another process that runs Blender with these arguments.

```
import subprocess


def run_blender(blender, project, script):
    output = subprocess.check_output([blender,
                                      project,
                                      '--background',
                                      '--python', script,
                                      '--render-output', '//frame_',
                                      '--render-frame', '0'])
    print(output.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Fixed a mistake in the argument order.

Comment: Cool, have you ever tried `plumbum`  I'm addicted to it.

Comment: @batFINGER no I haven't, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @rjg Could you please edit this code, add random filepath(arguments), so I know where to put it and how to use it and etc
I'm pretty new to coding and blender, I don't understand much. Thanks in advance for helping me

Answer (score 2):

Start with the basics

```
blender --background my.blend --python myscript.py
```

where myscript.py contains your logic and

```
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

To produce the render

in your script you can change just about anything e.g.

```
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format='PNG'
```

[Set the output filename](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3738/how-to-set-render-filepath-using-blend-filename-in-python)

You can also pass parameters and include multiple python scripts.

Comment: So I've to create a Script.py
and type these lines in it:
blender --background my.blend --python myscript.py
Right?

Comment: @cxnt no that is what you type on the command line to start blender and run the script stored in myscript.py

Comment: I ran it in windows 10 cmd, but it doesn't work
Should I use Linux?

Comment: No Windows is fine, this is likely because `blender` isn't in your PATH variable and thus it doesn't know what to do with that name. You can either give the full path to your blender.exe or switch to the directory and execute it there. So for example if your Blender is installed in `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\blender.exe` and your script and .blend file are in `C:\Users\user\Documents\Blender` then you would use `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\blender.exe --background C:\Users\user\Documents\Blender\my.blend --python C:\Users\user\Documents\Blender\myscript.py`.

Comment: @cxnt Adjust the paths to the ones were you actually stored the files.

Comment: This is what i get:

C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender>blender.exe --background C:\Users\7even\Documents\Blender\UnaEdited.blend --python C:\Users\7even\Documents\Blender\HairGenerationScript280.py
Blender 2.80 (sub 74) (hash 38d4483c6a51 built Thu 07/18/2019 09:28 AM)
AL lib: (EE) UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 48000hz, got 44100hz instead
found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\python
Read blend: C:\Users\7even\Documents\Blender\UnaEdited.blend

Blender quit

Comment: that looks fine. Did it write the render where you expected? Try without the --background parameter and Blender will open and stay open after everything has finished so you can check it did what you wanted.

Comment: @rjg so what if I want to apply two or three scripts on by one? is it possible?

Comment: @cxnt yes that is possible also via command line. You can simply add another `-P` or `--python` followed by the path to another script. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32986/run-multiple-python-scripts-in-blender-from-the-command-line