# Debug python script inside Blender with passing arguments

Tags: python, rendering

I'm trying to debug a python script in which passing arguments is required. Since I want to debug, using `-b` flag is not an option (otherwise there is no problem when running the code in a background mode).

I tried the following thing

```
filename = "/full/path/to/script.py --Arg1 arg1 ...."
exec(compile(open(filename).read(), filename, 'exec'))
```

Obviously that didn't work since `exec` tries to execute a file without additional arguments.

Few notes:

1) If I try to debug w/o passing arguments everything works fine I can debug and do what I want.

2) Some system pros: running docker container with 4 NVIDIA 1080-Ti cards on ubuntu os.

How can this be done?

Comment: [Do you want to pass the arguments as part of the command line arguments?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6817/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-blender-python-script)

Comment: @RobertGützkow |  These examples demonstrate passing arguments in a background mode Blender. I want to debug my code, hence I need to run it from Blender's GUI. Any suggestions?

Comment: Simply don't use the `-b` or `--background` argument? This will start Blender with GUI as usual.

Comment: @RobertGützkow | Tried that, doesn't work because I need to setup the connection to Pycharm debugger before I run the code.

Comment: Then it would be very helpful if you could give a precise description of what you're doing and what your goal is. I don't see why the PyCharm debugger wouldn't work when starting Blender from the command line, as long as the debugger is connected. Is this issue related to your [old question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153022/pycharm-remote-debugger)?

Comment: @RobertGützkow | No the old question solved. I have a code that I want to debug, this code includes passing arguments in order to run. What are the steps I should perform in order to be able to pass these arguments and debug the code? Is that more clear to you?

Comment: With the limited information available, I'd say create [two python scripts which are then called from the CLI](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32986/run-multiple-python-scripts-in-blender-from-the-command-line). The first script connects the debugger by calling the operator that implements this feature (e.g. `bpy.ops.debug.connect_debugger_pycharm` if you're using the add-on from the old answer). The second script is the one you would like to test and pass arguments to. It has to be the last CLI argument, followed by the arguments you would like to pass into the script.

Comment: @RobertGützkow Thank you for helping indeed this was the right way to do it. I wasn't aware of the fact that it is possible to activate the linkage between blender and pycharm through script.